# Javascript / JQuery add onto JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to working with JSON and I'm trying to construct an object that looks like:

```js
var newsAttachInfo = [{
  "fkAttachmentID": attachmentID,
  "enuAttachmentType": "thumbnail",
  "fldDisplayText": getCaption(attachmentID)
}, {
  "fkAttachmentID": $('#feature-top').val(),
  "enuAttachmentType": "feature-top",
  "fldDisplayText": getCaption($('#feature-top').val())
}, {
  "fkAttachmentID": $('#feature-bottom').val(),
  "enuAttachmentType": "feature-bottom",
  "fldDisplayText": getCaption($('#feature-bottom').val())
}];
```

However, I want to check if $('#feature-top').val() is 0 before adding that entry.  So, for a string it would be something like:

```
if ($('#feature-top').val() !== 0) {
  newsAttachInfo += { 
    "fkAttachmentID": $('#feature-top').val(),
    "enuAttachmentType": "feature-top",
    "fldDisplayText": getCaption($('#feature-top').val())
  }
}
```

How do I do something like that with the JSON?  Thanks!

Comment: `newsAttachInfo.fkAttachmentID = ...`, same way as any other object.  You're not working with JSON at that point.  You're working with an object.

Comment: `var x = '{"x": "y"}';` <= that is a variable with JSON.  `var x = { x: 'y' };` <= that is not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you're working with is an array of objects, not JSON.

To do what you require you can create your array with the two static objects and then dynamically add the third based on the value in `#feature-top` using `push()`, like this:

```js
var newsAttachInfo = [{
  "fkAttachmentID": attachmentID,
  "enuAttachmentType": "thumbnail",
  "fldDisplayText": getCaption(attachmentID)
}, {
  "fkAttachmentID": $('#feature-bottom').val(),
  "enuAttachmentType": "feature-bottom",
  "fldDisplayText": getCaption($('#feature-bottom').val())
}];

if ($('#feature-top').val() !== '0') {
  newsAttachInfo.push({
    "fkAttachmentID": $('#feature-top').val(),
    "enuAttachmentType": "feature-top",
    "fldDisplayText": getCaption($('#feature-top').val())
  });
}
```

Note in this example that I used `'0'` as `val()` returns a string. Using `===` to compare an int and a string will never match as it checks the values without coercing them to the same type.